# howto rollback failed release upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, btrfs, do-release-upgrade

Yesterday I did a "do-release-upgrade" to 18.04 that ended with a lot of errors and packages left unconfigured. Now I can only get a console.
I guess the reason for the failure is that a btrfs-snapshot of my system was made and the root Partition ran out of space.
Since I have a btrfs snapshot, I think I can undo the release upgrade and return to my old system. How do I do that?
Boot into the snapshot or better copy the snapshot over the current partition or switch the current volume with the snapshot subvolume?

Answer (score 2):

This was easy:

1. boot into a console or start a tty
2. `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`    (sda5 is the drive where / is mounted)
3. `ls -l /mnt`

now you should see a /mnt/@ which is the new system and a /mnt/@snapshot... which is the old system. Exchange the new system with the old system:

4. `sudo mv /mnt/@ /mnt/@failed`
5. `sudo mv /mnt/@snapshot... /mnt/@`

and reboot. That was it.