# How to make a quick shot before upgrade system?

Tags: upgrade

How to make a quick shot before upgrade the system? so I can roll back quickly if met some errors which are so hard to resolve.

Just like the behaviour in VMware.

Comment: If using *btrfs* you can rollback changes, eg. refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033990/howto-rollback-failed-release-upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way (I am familiar with) to have a backup installation, in case anything breaks, is to use something like [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) to backup your installation.

It is very easy to use, you only need a suitable place for your backed up information.

Or you could try [TimeShift](https://teejeetech.com/2017/10/01/timeshift-v17-10/).
Or [BackInTime](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime).

There are quite a few posts out there with variants.

1. [Create bootable backup of my existing ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129991/create-bootable-backup-of-my-existing-ubuntu-installation)
2. https://superuser.com/questions/355212/how-can-i-backup-a-ubuntu-system-and-restore-it-on-another-maching-with-complete
3. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2244774 (old)

Comment: +1; I use [Clonezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958242/fastest-way-to-copy-hdd/958248#958248) too.